# Thread-safe RNG Android NDK

Tags: android, linux, multithreading, prng

Is there a thread-safe RNG in Bionic?  For Linux, I know there is `rand_r()`, but this is unfortunately not a part of the NDK.

Comment: The Linux man pages say `rand_r` is obsolete.  `random_r` seems to be current... but it too doesn't exist in bionic.  There are a lot of open-source RNGs out there, tuned to different things (speed, low periodicity, etc), so you may just want to grab one and build it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply read from `/dev/urandom/` to get pseudo-random bytes. If you need this for cryptographic purposes, you may want to look into OpenSSL as well.